Rust HashMap with functions adhering Sync and Send traits
I'm trying to put function references into a HashMap. The functions get constructed during runtime using the meval crate like so:
let expr: meval::Expr = "x + y".parse().unwrap();
let func = expr.bind2("x", "y").unwrap(); // Is of type "impl Fn(f64, f64) -> f64"

Additionally I have the following struct containing a HashMap in which i want to put the function reference in:
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct
where
    Self: Send + Sync,
{
    pub dispatcher: HashMap<String, ???>,
}

The struct derives the Clone trait and has to be Send and Sync. I'm currently trying to test some changes within a big library so this I don't want to change at the moment and want to take it for granted. Otherwise many other things will have to be changed.
So I'm not sure what type I should use for the values in the map. I tried the following:
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct
where
    Self: Send + Sync,
{
    pub dispatcher: HashMap<String, Arc<dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64 + Send + Sync>>,
}

Now the struct compiles, but I can't put the function reference from the meval crate into the map:
type FunctionPointer = Arc<dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64 + Send + Sync>;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct DispatcherWrapper
where
    Self: Send + Sync,
{
    pub dispatcher: HashMap<String, FunctionPointer>,
}

fn foo() {
    let mut map = HashMap::<String, FunctionPointer>::new();
    let expr: meval::Expr = "x + y".parse().unwrap();
    let func = expr.bind2("x", "y").unwrap(); // Is of type "impl Fn(f64, f64) -> f64"
    map.insert("foo".to_owned(), Arc::new(func));
}


Above code leads to the following compiler error:
error[E0277]: `Rc<dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a [f64]) -> Result<f64, FuncEvalError>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> test.rs:140:34
    |
140 |     map.insert("foo".to_owned(), Arc::new(func));
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Rc<dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a [f64]) -> Result<f64, FuncEvalError>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `(std::string::String, Rc<dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a [f64]) -> Result<f64, FuncEvalError>>)`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `Rc<dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a [f64]) -> Result<f64, FuncEvalError>>`, which is required by `impl Fn(f64, f64) -> f64 + '_: Send`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `(std::string::String, Rc<dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a [f64]) -> Result<f64, FuncEvalError>>)`
    = note: required for `hashbrown::raw::RawTable<(std::string::String, Rc<dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a [f64]) -> Result<f64, FuncEvalError>>)>` to implement `Send`

I don't really understand the error message. Does anyone have an explanation?
Also it is confusing for me that suddenly the error message somehow recognizes the following signature: Fn(&'a [f64]) -> Result<f64, FuncEvalError> even though the IDE tells me that expr.bind2("x", "y").unwrap() returns the type impl Fn(f64, f64) -> f64.
Thanks in advance.

Sorry but you're out of luck. The result of meval .bind2() and related functors do not express that they are thread-safe. And indeed the compiler error leaks they are using Rc internally which can't be sent between threads.

Regarding the signature confusion: you are getting a impl Fn(f64, f64) -> f64 but internally it is built from a Fn(&'a [f64]) -> Result<f64, FuncEvalError> intermediate type. The compiler is not saying they are supposed to be the same.

Alright, thanks a lot. I understand both of your points. I guess I can hack around this for my purpose.
I was indeed also wondering where the single Rc was coming from as i explicit was using Arc.
